# bind gridview using case statement in linq

Tags: divider

```
private void BindGrid()
{

   var grid = (from a in dbcon.M_Linqs

    join b in dbcon.M_Countries on a.Country equals b.CId
                join c in dbcon.M_States on a.State equals c.SId orderby a.Id 
                select new
                {
                    a.Id,
                    a.Name,
                    Country = b.CountryName,
                    State = c.StateName,
                    Gender = a.Gender == 1 ? "Male" : a.Gender == 2 ? "Female" : "-",
                    Hobby = a.Hobby = 1 ? "Cricket" : a.Hobby = 2 ? "Hockey" : a.Hobby=12?"CriCket,Hobby":"-"
                }).ToList();
```

I want to bind gridview in which hobby column having integer value like 1 and 2 . if user enter 1 then it have to show Cricket if 2 then Hockey and ia 1,2 then Cricket,Hockey..
thanks in advance...

Comment: I dont want to use ternury operator... plz...

Answer (score 0):

From a relational databases point of view you should have a table called Gender and a table called Hobby.

For example, Gender would have columns for ID and GenderName e.g. 1, Male and then you could simply join to this table and select the GenderName.